# How to target multi divs with 1 java

Tags: javascript, html

I have the code `<a href="javascript:light.toggle('div1');">` i got this but i need to add `div2` also and when i do `('div1,div2')` everything breaks Any idea on how i need to go about doing this? Any ideas are greatly appreciated!

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: You'll have to provide some context for people to understand your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this? This will execute light.toggle('div1') and then light.toggle('div2')

```
 <a href="javascript:light.toggle('div1');light.toggle('div2');">
```

Comment: Didnt seem to work :/ when i use just div 1 it works but it only works on that div but when i try that code you gave me or the one i had neither work :/

Comment: Can you post more code? There might be some other issue with your code. https://jsfiddle.net/yf9w4fx1/

Comment: `<li>
<a href="javascript:light.toggle('div1');light.toggle('div2);">  <img src="image.png" style="margin-top:-15px;"/></a>
</li>`
        is the code im using. works fine when left 
`<li>
<a href="javascript:light.toggle('div1');">  <img src="image.png" style="margin-top:-15px;"/></a>
</li>`
idk why the 2nd is breaking it :/

Comment: `<a href="javascript:light.toggle(div1);javascript:light.toggle('div2');" >` Now this is working but its ONLY div2 working lol but 1 is not

Comment: can you create an example on jsfiddle and post it?